# Javascript dynamically removing duplicate innerHTMLs

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dynamic, innerhtml

In the code below, I have two `<span>` elements created using the `document.createElement('span')`. I have set both `<span>`'s innerHTML to be identical. My question is it possible to remove duplicate innerHTML values?

```
    spanContainer = [];
    spanContainer[0] = document.createElement('span');
    spanContainer[0].innerHTML = 'text';

    spanContainer[1] = document.createElement('span');
    spanContainer[1].innerHTML = 'text';
```

How can I ***dynamically*** remove duplicate innerHTML values?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you trying to avoid having to write `'text'` twice?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const spanContainer = [];
const arrayStr = []
function Unic(str){
  if(arrayStr.indexOf(str)== -1){
    arrayStr.push(str)
    spanContainer[0] = document.createElement('span');
    spanContainer[0].innerHTML = str;
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save it in a variable first, then assign to both elements:

```
const spanContainer = [];
const html = 'text';
spanContainer.push(document.createElement('span'));
spanContainer.push(document.createElement('span'));
spanContainer[0].innerHTML = html;
spanContainer[1].innerHTML = html;
```

It's not recommended because it's less readable, but you can also use the resulting expression from the assignment operator to condense it into one line:

```
spanContainer[0].innerHTML = spanContainer[1].innerHTML = html;
```

Or, with a helper function:

```
const spanContainer = [];
const html = 'text';
const makeElement = (tagName, html) => {
  const element = document.createElement(tagName);
  element.innerHTML = html;
  spanContainer.push(element);
};
makeElement('span', html);
makeElement('span', html);
```

If the HTML you're assigning really contains only text, like in this example, then you should assign to `textContent` rather than `innerHTML` - only use `innerHTML` when assigning or retrieving *HTML markup*. `textContent` is faster, safer, and more semantically appropriate otherwise.

```
element.textContent = text;
```